# Puppet class missing even when file exists

Tags: puppet

The directory structure of the puppet repo is as:

```
.
|-- data
|   |-- common.yaml
|-- environment
|   |-- environment.conf
|   `-- hiera.yaml
|-- files
|   `-- cdn
|-- hiera
|   `-- hiera.yaml
|-- hiera.global.yaml
|-- manifests
|   `-- site.pp
|-- modules
|   
`-- site
    |-- profile
    |   |-- files
    |   `-- manifests
    |       |-- appliance
    |       |   |-- base.pp
    `-- role
        `-- manifests
            |-- README.md
            `-- role1
                `-- appliance.pp
```

The site.pp file is as :

```
File { backup => false }


if $::custom_facts['appliance_type'] == 'Delivery' {
  include role::role0::app
}

if $::custom_facts['appliance_type'] == 'Appliance' {
  include role::role1::appliance **// line where error is occuring**
}

node default {
}
```

When I run the puppet apply command it fails with this error:

**`Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::role::role1::appliance for default-puppetmaster-centos-7.vagrantup.com (file: /tmp/kitchen/manifests/site.pp, line: 9, column: 3) on node default-puppetmaster-centos-7.vagrantup.com`**

The puppet command that is applied:

**`sudo -E /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet apply /tmp/kitchen/manifests/site.pp --modulepath=/tmp/kitchen/modules --fileserverconfig=/tmp/kitchen/fileserver.conf  --environment=kitchen_vagrant_puppet --environmentpath=/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments   --hiera_config=/tmp/kitchen/hiera.global.yaml`**

I cant figure out why puppet cannot find the class. The class is in the role folder. Is the directory structure wrong?

Edit:

Adding contents of `envirnment.conf` file:

```
modulepath          = site:modules:$basemodulepath
```

Comment: Your layout deviates substantially from Puppet's defaults.  This is one reason why you need so many command-line options.  Among the ways it deviates is in having your modules in directory `./site`, which is not on the module path by default.  No doubt you could address that by additional command-line options and/or by config-file tweaking, but perhaps you would make your life easier by reorganizing into a layout that Puppet handles automatically.

Comment: The site directory was added according to the docs in order for profiles and roles. Is there another way for using them?

Comment: I don't know which docs you're talking about, but either you have misinterpreted them or they are incomplete.  You can have additional module directories, but if you do, you need to add them to your module path.  You don't need that for roles and profiles, however.  The modules in which they reside are not qualitatively distinct from any other.  They can go into directories that are on your default module path, such as your `./modules`.

Comment: https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.2/r_n_p_full_example.html. The site directory is added to module path in the `environment.conf` file. Edited the question to show contents of `environment.conf` also. I will try adding the roles and profile in module directory and see how it goes though.

Comment: It did work when I added the role and profile directory in the modules folder. Maybe I did misinterpret the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this just because the modulepath needs to include `site`? Your manifests are in `site` rather than `modules`.

```
sudo -E /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet apply /tmp/kitchen/manifests/site.pp \
    --modulepath=/tmp/kitchen/modules:/tmp/kitchen/site \
    --fileserverconfig=/tmp/kitchen/fileserver.conf \
    --environment=kitchen_vagrant_puppet \
    --environmentpath=/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments \
    --hiera_config=/tmp/kitchen/hiera.global.yaml
```

I'd check the `modulepath` in `environment.conf`, too, just in case.

Comment: I have added the contents of environment.conf file.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the site directory path in the module path explicitly worked. Not sure why it dint work using the `environment.conf` file